# Unable to delete files from within smplayer

Tags: debian, permissions, filesystems, rm, mediaplayer

smplayer has an option that allows deleting the currently playing video. This worked well in windows 7, and even in debian 9 till about an year back. It brings up a confirmation dialog box, and if I click 'yes' it deletes the file and starts playing the next file in the playlist.

I tried it recently (now debian 10 buster, both kde & gnome. Both mplayer and mpv engine.) and it does not delete the file (When I click 'Delete File from Disk', nothing happens. Closing the app, also does not delete the file.). Tried files placed on both 'home' (ext4) and ntfs, same result.

Could you tell me why/how it can be solved?

If you have smplayer installed, could you please test it?

To get the delete button onto the toolbar (its not available by right clicking on the video, even last year when it was working well it was like that), you will need to:

Right click on the toolbar.
Select "Edit Main Toolbar".
Then find and select 'Delete File from Disk' from the 'Available Actions'.
Now it will appear on the toolbar and can be used when a video is playing.

---

Another test:

I opened smplayer from the terminal,
then opened a file using Ctrl+F
and then tried to delete the file, hoping so get some error messages, but there was nothing!

> u@p:~$ smplayer
>
> QObject::connect: No such signal MyApplication::commitDataRequest(QSessionManager)
>
> This is SMPlayer v. 17.11.2 (revision 8807) running on Linux
>
> u@p:~$

Comment: Can you share any more details about how it "doesn't work"? Any error messages? Do the files get removed if you then exit the app?

Comment: @Jeff - Thanks for checking it. I have added more details, are you able to understand what I mean?

Comment: Much better; it sounds like a bug or change in behavior of some sort; the Debian maintainer(s) may need to address it, but we have some smart Debian folks here as well. The question is at least reproducible and answerable now.

Comment: Lauch smplayer from the shell and try to delete a file. Post the message displayed on the terminal.

Comment: @sage - Thank You. I have done that, please check my edits above.